# Is there a way to send function context to model in nodejs mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to implement pre hooks in mongoose that are based on the id of the user that does the request.

I can't access the initial function context (userId, permissions, etc) and use it in mongoose pre hooks.

```
let writePermissionCondition = async function(next) {
    let ctx = getCurrentContext();
    next();
}
```

As I can't send the current context in the mongoose model, I can't access the userId that does the actual request.

Edit: a little more info on the architecture and what I'm trying to achieve

1) The user makes a request to the service (listening to events. ex: user/create, user/delete, user/find, etc)

2) The event calls a CRUD function

3) The Model used in the CRUD has ReadPermission and WritePermission middlewares (hooks)

4) The ReadPermission and WritePermission verifies the user that makes the request if, in fact, has permissions to read or write. This is the step where I need to know what user tried to access that Model.

I might be wrong, and the permissions should be implemented in the controller and not in the model.

Comment: could you add a sample code of your `getCurrentContext()` implementation? This will be helpful in order to have a good answer for your problem.

Comment: you initial question was about a mongoose problem "_I can't access the initial function context (userId, permissions, etc) and use it in mongoose pre hooks_" and two answers were given. After you edit, this question has become about a suggested architecture: "_a little more info on the architecture and what I'm trying to achieve...permissions should be implemented in the controller and not in the model_". If you have an architecture-related doubt create another question and keep this question about the original problem. Btw: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Set it to global var and use it on mongoose operation

```
let writePermissionCondition = async function(next) {
    let ctx = getCurrentContext();
    global.ctx = ctx
    next();
}
```

Now you can access `global.ctx` anywhere in the application.

Comment: I could. But let's say you have 100 concurrent users that use this function. I need to know to userId of the user making the request when I call 'writePermissionCondition'

Comment: global data of each request will be managed differently, so there is no problem. global is not a common place like database.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose provides many useful tools for solving complex situations like your question.

In your case you can user mongoose [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals):

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get persisted to MongoDB.

You can start trying with a simple implementation like this:

```
yourSchema.virtual('context').
  get(function() { return this.__context; }).
  set(function(ctx) {
    this.__context = ctx; 
  });
```

In this way you can call `getCurrentContext();` where the context is available (e.g. during express req/res flow) and save it the model you've retrieved.

Example flow (pseudocode):

```
const user = User.get(req.id)
const context = getCurrentContext();
user.context = context;
//... save/update...
```

Now, when the user will be saved/updated, and your pre hooks are called, your validation code can access the `context` variable attached to retrieve your data.